# Is there any database model designer that can output SQLAlchemy models?

Tags: python, model, sqlalchemy, data-modeling

I am implementing a database model to store the 20+ fields of the iCal calendar format and am faced with tediously typing in all these into an SQLAlchemy model.py file.  Is there a smarter approach?  I am looking for a GUI or model designer that can create the model.py file for me.  I would specify the column names and some attributes, e.g, type, length, etc.

At the minimum, I need this designer to output a model for one table.  Additional requirements, in decreasing order of priority:

- Create multiple tables
- Support basic relationships between the multiple tables (1:1, 1:n)
- Support constraints on the columns.

I am also open to other ways of achieving the goal, perhaps using a GUI to create the tables in the database and then reflecting them back into a model.

I appreciate your feedback in advance.

Comment: See my comment to S.Lott below.  In my day job, I manage a team of developers on a product that has 400+ tables.

Answer (score 5):

There's another way yet to generate an SQLAlchemy model. You can use Vertabelo - it's an online tool for visual database designing. It's completely free for small projects.

After you created your model in Vertabelo, you will have to convert it to SQLAlchemy mapping classes by using a script available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Vertabelo/vertabelo-sqlalchemy).

**Simply follow provided below steps:**

- Download diagram as XML file (simply press an XML icon on the toolbar menu)
- Generate SQLAlchemy models

`./vertabelo_sqlalchemy.py -i your_diagram.xml -o model.py`

I know this is not a direct and perfect way, but hope it will suit you.

Answer (score 0):

"I would specify the column names and some attributes, e.g, type, length, etc."

Isn't that the exact same thing as

"tediously typing in all these into an SQLAlchemy model.py file"?

If those two things aren't **identical**, please explain how they're different.

Comment: I'm looking for a GUI to display a grid where I select the available types via dropdowns, pick varchar lengths where applicable, and the GUI then generates valid and appropriate SQLAlchemy syntax.  I don't want to type syntax.  This is tedious, and more importantly, error-prone.  Some of the errors that I may make may not be discovered until runtime.  I know that some folks enjoy handcoding hundreds of model fields, but I am not one of them.  I'd rather focus on solving the business problem rather than work on syntax.

Comment: There are several commercial and free model designers that generate DDL and these become very useful in larger projects.  I'm looking for the same concept, but one that is applicable to SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @Kevin P.: "I don't want to type syntax".  Yet, you have to type field names and make numerous design decisions.  I'm still lost as to how typing field names, typing the letters "varchar" and typing field lengths is "error-prone".  You have to do this in a GUI.  You have to do this in Python.  I can't see the difference yet.  Can you provide some more concrete and specific ways in which you don't type when using a GUI.  The letters "varchar" seem to be a trivial thing.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Kevin P.: "generate DDL" and generate Python are different; they're different languages.  DDL is SQL.  SQLAlchemy is Python -- much more terse than SQL.  Also.  You say "hundreds" in the comment but "20+" in the question.  Please update the question to be your **real** question if the number is wrong there.

Comment: No, it's not the same. If your designing a database 'by hand' don't you end up drawing diagrams on paper? I find it's much easierto grasp 'The Big Picture' if you have ... a big picture. A bad or missing relationship stands out on a digram. Then once you've got the schema worked out, why not let the computer turn it into SQLA code?

Answer (score 0):

I Just found [workbench_alchemy](https://github.com/PiTiLeZarD/workbench_alchemy) a script plugin for [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/).

Haven't used it much yet but it looks great so far!. Easy to install. There is an option to make output compatible with SQlite. The script logs inside MySQL Workbench, so you can see what's going on.

Also good for the tool chain is an SQL WB Plugin, [mysql-wb-exportsqlite](https://github.com/tatsushid/mysql-wb-exportsqlite/commits/master) that can export an SQlite create script.

I'm on MySQL Workbench 6.2 (Debian apt-get one), but the script also works with 6.3 vers.